# Play! framework 1.2.4 Root Context issue

Tags: playframework, glassfish, playframework-1.x

I have got a problem with application which used play framework. This Application is deployed as WAR on Glassfish server. I was set that the context root is for eg. /abc
So it means, that my application is available on http: //localhost/abc

When I try to access to this page it's open normally, but when i click some URL, this page is follows to for eg. http://localhost/second-page and produce 404 page not found error.

As You see that after move to another page, context root has been disappear. 
So I changed link manually to http://localhost/abc/second-page and page works well, because moving to other pages is works.

Did someone get this issue. I've hear that someone have this same problem on tomcat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the following in your `application.conf`:

```
application.baseUrl=http://localhost/abc/
```

(Another related config option would be `http.path`, although I don't think that is going to help here as the [Play framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration) states that it is ignored when application is deployed as a WAR.)